# BindingResult haserror() not working and gives only same answer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, error-handling

I want to write Binding result without JSP file and I wrote like this. But I get same result every time

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<?> submit(@RequestBody Employee employee,BindingResult bindingResult) throws EmployeeNotFoundException {
            if (!bindingResult.hasErrors())
               return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeRepository.save(employee), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    
        else{
        return new ResponseEntity<>(" not working", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Foremost, you should fix your formatting.

Comment: Secondly, you shout specify which request you are sending to your backend and maybe explain which result is being expected and what should trigger it

Comment: @micartey Firstly, thank you for telling me the fix my code. And it's just a test if it gives me my wanted result then I change the code. MY excepted answer is "not working"(because I give the wrong input for testing). And this request is "add" or "update" (it's just a test for the Binding result I'm trying to learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed `javax.validation.Valid` annotation for your request body :

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> submit(@Valid @RequestBody Employee 
employee,BindingResult bindingResult) throws EmployeeNotFoundException {
```

Once you have annotated your method with `Valid` annotation, your request body will get validated in controller layer & any validation related errors can be seen in your else block of  `if (!bindingResult.hasErrors())`.

Tip : You can also throw `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` in absence of  `BindingResult` in your method argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know what is the problem. In other word I tried your solution but I get same result again. Problem is the when I run the application it never see inputs(whatever they are true or false it gives "bindingResult.hasErrors()=false")  I can't find why it look like this. Actually I really don't know how to use it without jsp and want to learn it

Comment: please share how you are using this POST service , what is request body & what is expected here.

Comment: it's input I gave(additional info: I already add this to my database so it has to be give error )

{
    "id":"4",
    "firstName":"name",
    "lastName":"surname",
    "username":"nick221",
    "pin":"89876567",
    "mobile":"2761212",
    "salary":"23213",
    "active":"false"
}

And I want to get a "not working" message (It's not for work just for learning purposes I know how to give output with JSON format but when I learn I used this method)
It maybe show like little mess if you won't understand I'll put in my question part

Comment: I would recommend to do one thing here (if possible) : use simple curl or postman / soapui kind of tools & hit your webservice with your request body.  Use `Valid` annotation along with `@Validated` at controller level (if not used already), and see what you are getting from your webservice.

This way , if you are able to see desired result, you can then integrate with your JSP

Comment: Thanks for your response; I actually accidentally entered some dependencies that conflict with each other. So after I delete them, those application starts working normally(I mean I get the result I want to ). Of course, Your answer is helpful to me. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked for you..